# passing array of strings to wcf service error

Tags: arrays, web-services, wcf

I have a method that sometimes works, but sometimes it doesn't work. It doesn't throw an error, but instead just returns no data.

```
var infosvc = new InfoServiceClient();
var searchStrings = new string[]
                        {
                            "searchedstring" 
                        };
// if string[] searchStrings  is null then works, otherwise return no data
var status= infosvc.GetDataByParams(74, searchStrings );
infosvc.Close();
```

And here is the definition in the web service:

```
public List<LogEntry> GetDataByParams(int id, string[] searchStrings )
```

Here is the Service Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IInfoService
{
       [OperationContract]
       List<LogEntry> GetDataByParams(int instanceId, string[] searchStrings);
}
```

Comment: Please show the implementation (code) of `GetDataByParams`.

Comment: I don't think that it has anything to do with the inside of the function. When i test/debug it in the studio it works everytime. It has something to do with the string array that i am sending.

Comment: just for the kick change `string[]` to `List<string>` in the service only. Your .NET client will interpret `List<string>` as `string[]`

Comment: unfortunatelly, i tried that, but it didn't work either.

Comment: your issue is definitively a setting because the service you are describing is pretty normal. i have myself worked with alot of Web service and WCF services and this should work perfectly. I have the feeling you need to change the client setting as WCF default are very restrictive. try changing the timeout, max request length and stuff like that to allow more time and more data to be transferred.

Comment: Hi Franck, I have done this from the start. In my case this wasn't the problem :). Thanks.

Comment: hold on a sec, i just noticed you have a custom object as a return. you do have a `[DataContract]`to expose that `LogEntry` class don't you ?

Comment: Yeah, I have. I've done many wcf, just by now I haven't had the need to sent array.

Comment: I nearly only have array :) but i don't ever use `[DataContract]` because i need my services to work with different languages and not only .NET. my returns in those case i simply serialize a class as JSON and return the string value than my client apps can all read JSON easily no matter if it's Java, Java droid, objective C, ASP classic, PHP and .NET 2.0/4.0.

Comment: Yes. Kind of what I wrote below as answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There two ways i found out that works. Maybe later I will find out other, but i had need of fast colution.
1) serialize the array and pass it as a string to the web service and then deserialize in the web service 
2) if it is one dimension array (mainly), to concatinate the string and then split it in web service.

The two ways are kind of the same but also they aren't.